# Response returned to caller Method is empty with Java DSL

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration-dsl

I am using Spring boot project and my requirement is to call get a request from external client and send it another internal Rest Service. I am using Java DSL for the same and stuck when it comes to response handling. (One service calling another service). I have not included variable declaration here.
Below is the code snippet.

```
 //This is one class
    
    //Class A
    
    @Gateway
        public HttpRequestHandlerEndpointSpec getTestApi() {
            return Http.inboundGateway("/test")
                    .requestChannel(MessageChannels.direct("testRequest").get())
                    .replyChannel(MessageChannels.direct("testResponse").get())
                    .errorChannel("errorChannel").replyTimeout(REPLY_TIMEOUT);
        }
    
    @Gateway
        public HttpRequestHandlerEndpointSpec getFoobarApi() {
            return Http.inboundGateway("/foobar")
                    .requestChannel(MessageChannels.direct("foobarRequest").get())
                    .replyChannel(MessageChannels.direct("foobarResponse").get())
                    .errorChannel("errorChannel").replyTimeout(REPLY_TIMEOUT);
        }
    
    
    //This is in another class
    //Class B
    
    @Override
        protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
            return IntegrationFlows.from(httpGateway.getTestApi())
                    .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("Content-Type", "application/json"))
                    .gateway(outboundFlow());
        }
    
    
    
    private IntegrationFlow outboundFlow() {
            return flow -> flow
                    .handle(httpGateway.sendToHost("http://localhost:8080/foobar")
                            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                            .expectedResponseType(JSONObject.class))
                    .handle(jsonHelper, "handleJsonResponse"); // The value returned is empty object
            }
    
    
    //This is in another class
    //Class C
    
    @Override
        protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
            return IntegrationFlows.from(httpGateway.getFoobarApi())
                    .handle(responsMsg); // this method gets the Json Response
        }
```

However when the control goes to handleJsonResponse  Method after processing the getFoorbarApi, the response is an empty object.Can you please tell me where I am going wrong?